# Azure NotificationHubClient GetRegistrationsByTagAsync limiting results to 5 pages (500 records)

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Azure NotificationHubClient (Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs 1.0.9) calling the method GetRegistrationsByTagAsync on a console .NET 4.5 application, exactly like the code below (where I need get all registered devices with the tag "my_tag"):

```
    private async Task<List<RegistrationDescription>> GetAllRegisteredDevicesWithTagAsync()
    {
        var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(HUB_CONNECTION_STRING, "my_hub");
        var registrations = await hubClient.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync("my_tag", 100);
        var continuationToken = registrations.ContinuationToken;
        var allRegistrationDescriptions = new List<RegistrationDescription>(registrations);

        while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(continuationToken))
        {
            var moreRegistrations = await hubClient.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync("my_tag", continuationToken, 100);
            allRegistrationDescriptions.AddRange(moreRegistrations);
            continuationToken = moreRegistrations.ContinuationToken;
        }

        return allRegistrationDescriptions;
    }
```

The results in allRegistrationDescriptions are limited to 500 records (5 pages = 5 ContinuationToken's), and I have more than a 1000 registrations. May I am doing something wrong, or there is a bug with the method GetRegistrationsByTagAsync. Someone of you know how to get this working?

UPDATED: I tried with VS 2017 instead of the API and VS can't get the registrations too (the image show the total 2114 registrations).

[image: Azure server explorer VS 2017 Update 3]

Comment: I talked with Microsoft support and they found a invalid installation in my notification hub. After they delete this single record, the code I mentioned started working because it was causing a problem with the continuation token.

Answer (score 0):

What tier are you in? The number of registrations are limited to 500 for free tier.

Comment: I started at the free plan, but some months ago I changed to basic plan (200K active devices).